# How to upload all files from a folder to S3 bucket of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bulkinsert

This is the current code I am using to upload a single file from local folder to s3 bucket.

```
try {
        var filePath = "./data/1061827.png";

      var s3 = new AWS.S3();
      var params = {
        Bucket: "**************",
        Key: "folder/" + Date.now() + "_" + path.basename(filePath),
        Body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
      };
      s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
          }
          //success
          if (data) {
            console.log("Uploaded in:", data.Location);
            return data;
          }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
```

Currently onle one file from folder data is geting uploaded but what i want is to just give the folder address(in this case data) and all files from it get uploaded into S3 Bucket.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no API call** to upload multiple files to Amazon S3.

You would need to code a loop in your program and upload one file per API call.

Comment: Thanks for your time and I also know that there is no API available for this particular task. What I am unable to code is touching all files at once or onebyone available in the folder.

Comment: You would need to write code that obtains a listing of all the files on your computer in that folder, then loop through them and upload. For example: [Get List of all files in a directory in Node.js | by VithalReddy | stackFAME | Medium](https://medium.com/stackfame/get-list-of-all-files-in-a-directory-in-node-js-befd31677ec5)